# Replace value in specific column in CSV from hashtable

Tags: csv, powershell, hashtable

I have an imported CSV (`$csv`) with multiple headers, one of which is "Target Server". In the CSV this column has values device1, device2 etc.

I also have a hashtable (`$hash`) with name/value pairs of name(device1) - value(fqdn1) etc.

So I would like to replace the "device1" in CSV with the correct value from the hashtable, like:

```
foreach($row in $csv)
  if($hash[$_.Name]){
    $row."Target Server"= $hash[$_.Value]
  }
```

Am I getting warm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ContainsKey()` method to see if the hashtable contains an entry with a specific name/key:

```
foreach($row in $csv) {
    if($hash.ContainsKey($row.'Target Server')) {
        $row.'Target Server' = $hash[$row.'Target Server']
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I get error: Exception calling "ContainsKey" with "1" argument(s): "Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key"

How do I reference the specific csv column by name?

Comment: Actually it worked, I was passing $csv from memory during runtime from a previous operation. When I exported the previous result to a .csv and imported it assigning it to $csv it worked.